# I want the regular expression for the data of type dd.d.dd.ddddd or dd.d.d.ddddd

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want the regular expression for the data of type dd.d.dd.ddddd or dd.d.d.ddddd,each d is for a digit between 0-9 and the regular expression should represent both the formats. I am working in java script.I have tried the following code.but it is not working for all the input strings.

```
<p id="demo">my string</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
//var regExp1=/[1-4]+\.[1-4]+\.[1-4]+\.[0-9]+$/;

var regExp1=/[1-4][1-4]\.[1-4]\.[1-4][1-4]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;

//var regExp1=/[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;

var str="Version of C:\hjkl.dll:14.6.17.90505 working File Versn:18.1.9.17083,stopped file:13.1.14.25059 absjhdhgh";

var mystring=str.split(regExp1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=mystring;
}
</script>
```

Desired output is:

```
Version of C:\hjkl.dll:
 working File Versn:
,stopped file:
 absjhdhgh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
\d{2}\.\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d{5}
```

Example:

```
var str     = "Version of C:\hjkl.dll:14.6.17.90505 working File Versn:18.1.9.17083,stopped file:13.1.14.25059 absjhdhgh";
var regExp1 = /\d{2}\.\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d{5}/;

var output  = str.split(regExp1);
```

Output:

```
["Version of C:hjkl.dll:", " working File Versn:", ",stopped file:", " absjhdhgh"]
```

To join array's elements, use:

```
var newString = output.join("\n"); // or <br/> instead of \n
```

Comment: tried but not working.(I only changed the regExp1 value by this one.)plz suggest sth if possible.

Comment: @user2721608 if you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with a thick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Just match the simpler version and add an optional 2nd digit in the third group with `\d?`

```
\d\d\.\d\.\d\d?\.\d{5}
```

Comment: u mean..:14.6.17.90505 working File Versn:18.1.9.17083,stopped file:"13.1.14.25059" absjhdhgh...I need to change any digit in this one?...I applied it on the above code by replacing regExp1=\d\d\.\d\.\d\d?\.\d{5}; with same string but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
\b\d{2}\.\d\.\d{1,2}\.\d{5}\b
```